# How to access part of string contained in an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I have an object that looks like this

```
{'{"variable":"2","text":"fdsfdsfds","hotdog":"yes"}': '' }
```

I want to access part of what's contained in it

For example, if it was a normal object I would've thought I could do

```
objectName.variable
```

or

```
objectName.["variable"]
```

Comment: `objectName.["variable"]` -- this isn't a valid statement.

Comment: You have to restructure the object. Looks wierd.

Comment: Is the key of the object a JSON string? or you have misplaced some quotes

Comment: `JSON.parse(Object.keys(objectName)[0]).variable` but as Eddie noted already: You should rather correctly format it where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You should parse json data.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"variable":"2","text":"fdsfdsfds","hotdog":"yes"}');
console.log(obj.variable);
console.log(obj.text);
```

etc ...

Comment: Thank you, that was it, just needed to parse the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, parse the JSON - then because the data is a key, use `Object.keys`, then get the `variable` property:

```js
const obj = {'{"variable":"2","text":"fdsfdsfds","hotdog":"yes"}': '' };
const { variable } = JSON.parse(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
console.log(variable);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = {'{"variable":"2","text":"fdsfdsfds","hotdog":"yes"}': '' };
// get keys from obj
var keys = Obejct.keys(obj);
// loop keys array
keys.forEach((item) => {
   // !!! parse String to JSON !!!
   var parsedObj = JSON.parse(item);

   console.log(parsedObj.variable);
})
```

Comment: This code produces a ReferenceError and it's code-only.